# Lync 2013 Most Recent or Most Frequent contacts

Tags: microsoft-outlook, contacts, lync-2013

How can I get Lync 2013 to show me a list of my most recent and most frequent contacts?

I know that you can organize your contacts into groups and favorites. I would like to have a way to view my most recent and most contacts.

This would be much easier than trying to organize all my contacts into the perfect groups as I tend to chat with people in pretty repetitive patterns.